# Javascript Session time out countdown in progress bar

Tags: javascript, jsp

I need your help in getting the appropriate code for showing the count down for the session time out in the progress bar or any part of the screen.

However, these actions should be included:

First Alert: "You have 5 minutes before your session expires"
Click here to continue your session.
or
Click here to logout

if no action in 5 mins then change the page to display "Your session has expired" and will be redirected to logout.jsp.

I tried to find good examples, but I did not find anyone.

Can anyone help on that issue.

Comment: Funny, I just looked for "javascript session timeout" the other day and found several links like this: http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2005/01/30/friendly-session-timeouts-the-javascript-way. Guess you did not try hard enough.

Comment: I need detailed example since I am a beginner in this field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var timeoutHandle = null;
    function startTimer(timeoutCount) {
        if (timeoutCount == 0) {
            window.location.href = 'logout.jsp';
        } else if (timeoutCount < 3) {
            document.getElementById('sessionTimer').innerHTML = 'You have ' + (timeoutCount * 3000)/1000 + 'seconds until timeout' ;
        }
        timeoutHandle = setTimeout(function () { startTimer(timeoutCount-1);}, '3000');
    }
    function refreshTimer() {
        killTimer(timeoutHandle);
        startTimer(3);
    }
  </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="startTimer(3)">
  <div id="sessionTimer"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and regarding the directing to the logout.jsp where i should place the code?

Comment: No, sorry I don't have enough experience in this.

Comment: @user1080320 [May be this helpful?](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jspsessions.shtml)

Comment: See the updated code from this answer for how to redirect to logout.jsp